# Save all console out data to a new text file C++

Tags: c++, text-files, console-application

I'm beginning to think this is totally impossible...

I have a small console programme that is basically a small calculator, once the user has done one calculation and achieved a result the programme then loops to allow the user to do another calculation. As long as the user keeps choosing to add another calculation the programme is never ending.

Now what I would like is to be able to save ALL of the data displayed in the console to a new text file on the desktop.

I have a set of functions that declares a full file path and file name into a string, if possible I would like the programme to save the text file to this exact file path and name. If not possible then the user’s desktop will do fine.

So far I have tried Fstream but had no luck; maybe I'm doing something wrong? I'm kind of new to this all so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is ALL code from the programme.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   //creates file name
    char timeNow[20];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(timeNow, 20, "%d.%m.%Y %H%Mhrs", localtime(&now));

// Creates desktop file path that includes the users user name
char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
stringstream user;
string UserName;
user << username;
user >> UserName;
string pathName = "c:/users/" + UserName + "/desktop/" + timeNow + ".txt";

// Declare Variables
int suA, splitA, cornerA, streetA, sixlineA, payout;
double Cvalue = 1;
double cash;
int winnum = 0;
int table = 0;
std::string Another ("y");

// Programme Header
cout << "Roulette Bet Calculator & Payout Log!" << endl;
cout << "By Chris McCarthy" << endl << endl;

    //Bet Calculator Loop
    while (Another == "y") {
    cout << "Table no: AR";
    cin >> table;
    cout << "Winning Number? ";
    cin >> winnum;
    char timeNow[20];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(timeNow, 20, "%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y", localtime(&now));
    cout << timeNow << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the chip value? " << char(156);
    cin >> Cvalue;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of Straight Ups? ";
    cin >> suA;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of Splits? ";
    cin >> splitA;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of Corners? ";
    cin >> cornerA;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of Streets? ";
    cin >> streetA;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of Six Lines? ";
    cin >> sixlineA;
    cout << endl;

    // Calculates then writes the final payout and cash value
    payout  = (suA * 35) + (splitA * 17) + (cornerA * 8) + (streetA * 11) + (sixlineA * 5);
    cash = Cvalue * payout;
    cout << "The payout is: " << payout << endl;
    cout << "The cash value of the payout is: " << char(156) << cash << endl << endl;

    // Adds another bet or terminates programme
    cout << "Add another bet? (y/n) ";
    cin >> Another;
    cout << "____________________________________________________________" << endl << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"So far I have tried Fstream but had no luck; maybe I'm doing something wrong?"_ Yes. You did something wrong. Nobody is able to say more, as nobody knows what exactly you tried.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it is obvious I done something wrong. I Googled the hell out of this and have basically came up with nothing. Is it even possible?

Comment: _"So far I have tried Fstream but had no luck"_ - is not a good problem statement. Based on the answer you accepted you have errors in your code but you did not call them out and other issues related to your problem. This is important when you post on SO because we're not going to try different things or examine your code without knowing what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++98 Formation of [ofstream open()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) is:

```
void open (const char* filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
```

Your pathName is string type. Copying the pathName value in char array and passing it in open() method worked in my pc.

So what I did **(!!!)**, declared a char array and copied pathName into that array and use it in open().

```
char pname[100] = {'\0'};
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(pname); i++) {
    pname[i] = pathName[i];
}

std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open (pname, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

and right after each

```
cout << ... << endl;
```

I put

```
ofs << ...<< endl;
```

which generated a file in my desktop named "27.04.2016 1643hrs.txt" and I got these string inside the file:

```
Roulette Bet Calculator & Payout Log!
By Chris McCarthy

Table no: ARWinning Number? 16:43:19 27/04/2016

Please enter the chip value? œPlease enter the amount of Straight Ups? Please enter the amount of Splits? Please enter the amount of Corners? Please enter the amount of Streets? Please enter the amount of Six Lines? 
The payout is: 238
The cash value of the payout is: œ238

Add another bet? (y/n) ____________________________________________________________
```

Don't forget to include "#include <fstream>" in header

Comment: Fantastic! Thank You! So basically the filepath had to be converted from a String to a Char to be used as the path for file.open. I have managed to get all of the cout to save to the file, now how would I go about saving the cin to the file, basically so the .txt file is almost a replica of the console?

Comment: Never mind, managed to crack it. example... cout << "Please enter the amount of Straight Ups? ";
        cin >> suA;
        ofs << endl << "Please enter the amount of Straight Ups? " << suA;

Answer (score 0):

Use ofstream, `ofstream consoleCopy; consoloeCopy.open(filepath);` where filepath is the path you generate with your functions.  Then it's just a matter of writing to the file, `consoleCopy << consoleString;`.

To achieve what you want, though, you're going to need to either store all of the output/input into a string and write it to the file at the end, or write to the file as you go.  The following site should help you with writing to files, http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Thank you. Just had a read through, sounds promising, will give it a shot!